# Converting multi-dimensional numpy array elements to strings WITHOUT converting to scientific notation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a **multi-dimensional** numpy array with float elements. I want to convert the elements to strings, but NOT have the elements change to scientific notation.

An example:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

x = np.array([0.000095]) # prints as "[0.000095]"
x = x.astype(str) # this is now "['9.5e-05']", whereas I want "['0.000095']"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use np.nditer to achieve this for multidimensional arrays

let

```
my_multidimensional_array = np.ones((3,3,3)) * 0.000095

my_multidimensional_array
Out[105]: 
array([[[0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095],
        [0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095],
        [0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095]],

       [[0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095],
        [0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095],
        [0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095]],

       [[0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095],
        [0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095],
        [0.000095, 0.000095, 0.000095]]])

def np_to_string(my_multidimensional_array):
    result = my_multidimensional_array.copy().astype(str)
    with np.nditer(result, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
        for x in it:
            x[...] = np.format_float_positional(float(x))

    return result
```

And it works!

```
print(np_to_string(my_multidimensional_array))
[[['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']
  ['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']
  ['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']]

 [['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']
  ['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']
  ['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']]

 [['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']
  ['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']
  ['0.000095' '0.000095' '0.000095']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use np.format_float_positional function to convert to string

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
y = []
x = np.array([0.000095,0.2131]) # prints as "[0.000095]"
for item in x:
    y.append(np.format_float_positional(item))
```